# Android update RemoteAction icon in picture in picture mode

Tags: android, picture-in-picture

I need to update the RemoteAction icon when the activity is in PiP mode.

```
RemoteAction myAction = new RemoteAction(myIcon, "title", "description", myPendingIntent);
ArrayList<RemoteAction> actions = new ArrayList<>();
actions.add(myAction);
myActivity.setPictureInPictureParams(new PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
    .setActions(actions)
    .build());
```

Is there a way to update the icon when pressing it?

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // update the remote action icon here
    }
}
```